# Loading bearing wall?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, architecture

I'm looking to determine whether the indicated wall is load bearing.  I am looking to move the indicated wall several feet "upwards" based on the photo, shrinking the bathroom.  There is no nearby wall on the floor below, and the diagram does not appear to me to indicate anything special about this wall.

I have circled 2 markings ("s") which I believe indicate load bearing in other walls.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement!  For load bearing, the concern is usually walls or joists above the wall of concern, not below.  Are there rafters tying in?  Also, is this wall likely to have plumbing in it?

Comment: There is a third floor above this with a knee wall in that area, but does not appear structural.  There is definitely no plumbing in this wall.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking for "opinions" is explicitly off-topic at almost all SE sites including this one, so I reworded your question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if that wall is a load bearing wall because:

1. It is too close to the exterior wall,
2. It does not extend completely through the house,
3. The wall adjacent to fireplace has two double width areas that could accommodate a 4x4 and extends through the house.

However, before you start removing the wall, I’d check to see if there’s a footing under one of the walls and if the roof framing (including the 4x4’s from above) are resting on which wall. A quick look in the attic should show that.